# How to use SQL Task to update a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis-2008, sqlcommandbuilder

I have this SQL to update modified records in my table. It runs in SSMS, but how do I implement this in SSIS package? I tried to use SQL task but it does not recognize the columns.

I can put a select within a data flow ole db source (sql command has select statement), derived column for my import date, then ole db destination to update the records - but what is the syntax of the sql command to update?

```
update nss.MKT_CUSTOM
set 
      [INSURED_NUMBER] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[INSURED_NUMBER]
      ,[SALES_AGENCY_NUMBER] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[SALES_AGENCY_NUMBER]
      ,[PRODUCT_CODE] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[PRODUCT_CODE]
      ,[INS_MKT_INFO_SRC_CREATE_DATE] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[INS_MKT_INFO_SRC_CREATE_DATE]
      ,[INS_MKT_INFO_SRC_CREATE_USER] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[INS_MKT_INFO_SRC_CREATE_USER]
      ,[MKT_INFO_SRC_CODE] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[MKT_INFO_SRC_CODE]
      ,[MKT_INFO_SRC_DESC_EN] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[MKT_INFO_SRC_DESC_EN]
      ,[MKT_INFO_SRC_DESC_FR] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[MKT_INFO_SRC_DESC_FR]
      ,[MKT_INFO_SRC_START_DATE] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[MKT_INFO_SRC_START_DATE]
      ,[MKT_INFO_SRC_END_DATE] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[MKT_INFO_SRC_END_DATE]
      ,[MKT_INFO_SRC_CREATE_DATE] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[MKT_INFO_SRC_CREATE_DATE]
      ,[MKT_INFO_SRC_MOD_DATE] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[MKT_INFO_SRC_MOD_DATE]
      ,[MKT_INFO_SRC_CLIENT_CODE] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[MKT_INFO_SRC_CLIENT_CODE]
      ,[MKT_INFO_SRC_CAT_CODE] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[MKT_INFO_SRC_CAT_CODE]
      ,[MKT_INFO_SRC_CAT_DESC_EN] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[MKT_INFO_SRC_CAT_DESC_EN]
      ,[MKT_INFO_SRC_CAT_DESC_FR] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[MKT_INFO_SRC_CAT_DESC_FR]
      ,[MKT_INFO_SRC_CAT_CREATE_DATE] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[MKT_INFO_SRC_CAT_CREATE_DATE]
      ,[MKT_INFO_SRC_CAT_MOD_DATE] = stg_MKT_CUSTOM.[MKT_INFO_SRC_CAT_MOD_DATE]
      ,[IMPORT_DATE] = GETDATE()
from 
    nss.stg_MKT_CUSTOM
inner join
    MKT_CUSTOM on (stg_MKT_CUSTOM.INS_MKT_INFO_SRC_ID = MKT_CUSTOM.INS_MKT_INFO_SRC_ID)
where 
    (stg_MKT_CUSTOM.MKT_INFO_SRC_MOD_DATE <> MKT_CUSTOM.MKT_INFO_SRC_MOD_DATE 
     or stg_MKT_CUSTOM.MKT_INFO_SRC_CAT_MOD_DATE <> MKT_CUSTOM.MKT_INFO_SRC_CAT_MOD_DATE)
```

Comment: Can you do it in an Execute SQL Task?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform an update action within data flow task, you need to use OLE DB Command component.

However as I cannot see any parameters/variables within your statement, you can try to use Execute Sql Task in control flow panel.

Comment: I do have it in Execute SQl task (in control flow panel). When I run it, my exe results shows this error:[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "update nss.MKT_CUSTOM
set 
[INSURED_NUMBER] = stg_..." failed with the following error: "Incorrect syntax near ')'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not figure out the error from your statement without knowing your table's structure. If the above statement can be run in SSMS, what you can do is 1 adding a using clause to verify connection issue 2 ensure the option in resultset is NONE, 3 change BypassPrepare to false, and click Parse Query button to verify your sql statement in the component is correct

Answer (score 0):

i this case i try to put your update in a new sql procedure,
and in execute sql-task I try to execute it.